# C#, need to receive data from microcontroller

Tags: c#, serial-port, microcontroller, uart

Trying to receive data, from mk, using  DataReceived and handler event, what i do is -
push a button on a program (code is below) then LED on mk will turn on, then the data should be sent back to program (expecting 1, on byte value, but also tried string value, doesn't work). Sending side is working, but receiving....not
seems like i'm missing something. Any help apreciate it. Thx in Further

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // As i understood, here we configure where i data will be shown,
                                                                                       // trying to get it on TextBox1
        {

            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            richTextBox1.Text += sp.ReadExisting() + "\n";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                      // There are a main actions, first i receive data then send data by a click.    
        {
            serialPort1.Write("\u0001");
            serialPort1.Close();

            System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();  //  
            serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to wire up your listener before your write.  It looks like the pin is turned on but nothing was listening to receive the information.  By the time you start listening to the port nothings going on.

Comment: I suggest you to use a serial port emulator to debug the issue so you can find out exactly what is going on and make sure there is an incoming communication.

Comment: Thx you for you comments, as i said my devices is working i can send data, and i also checked receiving data with console(using c# too), and i received a data i send from mk. Therefore problem in my code above. Any help in correct my code kindly apreciate it,

Comment: Why do you first write and close and then create the port? shouldn't you first create the port? then write and read?

Comment: Yeah, i changed it, assigned to button click. But the result is the same

Comment: So, Update the code in your post, so we can see the most current one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial port is on a different thread than the UI. So when you receive a character, as you haven't invoked the UI, you get an exception and the UI is not updated.
Invoke the UI first in your `DataReceivedHandler`. You could do something like that:

```
public static class ControlExt
{
    public static void InvokeChecked(this Control control, Action method)
    {
        try
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(method);
            }
            else
            {
                method();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeChecked(delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadExisting() + "\n";

            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        });
    }
}
```