# C# - SerialPort Encoding help needed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I need help with my program with which I want to read codes from several microcontrollers simultaneously and translate them into plain text. There is only one serial interface where all codes are collected. The translation of the codes works, but I have the problem that the codes are not read correctly. He makes pauses again and again where there are no gaps and where there are gaps (500 micro sec. ) He doesn't always recognize them correctly.

Here's part of the code:

```
public byte[] block = new byte[4096];
        public int posBlock = 0;

        public void Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            console_.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            console_.WriteLine("Void: Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)");
            int offset = 0, count = serialPort.BytesToRead, i = 0;
            byte[] rd = new byte[count];

            serialPort.Read(rd, offset, count);

            for (int buffer = 0; buffer < count; buffer++) { block[posBlock + buffer] = rd[buffer]; i = buffer; }
            i++;
            posBlock += i;
            string rcpausgabe = null;
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < posBlock; i2++) { rcpausgabe += " " + (int)(block[i2]); }
            //WriteProtocol(global_.variables.protocol_other, rcpausgabe, true);
            console_.WriteLine("ReadCode: " + rcpausgabe);
            if (IsDecode == false) { Zersetzten(); } else { console_.WriteLine("Add but not Zersetzen()"); }
            IsDecode = false;
            console_.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
        }

        bool IsDecode = true;
        public int ib = 0;
        public string bs = null;

        private void Zersetzten()
        {
            IsDecode = true;
            console_.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            console_.WriteLine("Void: Zersetzten()");

            byte[] b = new byte[4096];

            while (!(ib >= posBlock))
            {
                for (int i7 = 0; i7 < b[1] + 3; i7++)
                {
                    string rcpausgabe1 = null;
                    b[i7] = block[ib];
                    ib++;;
                    if (i7+1 == (b[1] + 3))
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        console_.WriteLine("Decoding b");
                        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < b[1]+3; i2++) { rcpausgabe1 += " " + (int)(b[i2]); }
                        console_.WriteLine("Decoding Code: " + rcpausgabe1);
                        bs = rcpausgabe1;                        
                        Decoding(b);
                    }                    
                }
            }
            IsDecode = false;
            block = new byte[4096];
            posBlock = 0;
            ib = posBlock;
            console_.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

I have programmed my own console (console_) to help me with this, which allows me to track all processes in real time.

I also thank everyone for their answers in advance.

(I translated this text with Pons translator because my english is not so good)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I have to use post to help you clarify your question.
I'll edit my answer if you could provide more detail.

1. Make your question clearer.

   What result do you expect and what kind of phenomena do you observe.
2. Make [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

   Apparently `Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)` is not called inside of your post.

   While your problem is reading is "paused", which piece of code is calling `Read` could be essential.
3. What is "pause" and what is "Gap".

   > He makes pauses again and again where there are no gaps and where there are gaps (500 micro sec.

   I could only guess your program will "pause" when there is a gap, but having no idea about what "gap" and "pause" are.
4. What does `for (int i7 = 0; i7 < b[1] + 3; i7++)` and `for (int i2 = 0; i2 < b[1]+3; i2++)` want do achieve?

   You're using b[1] for indexing and b[1] is changed while you're receiving data.

Edit: Adding How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
Edit2: Point out a strange piece of code in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong with you about the code you provided.

However, you could refer to [[C#, need to receive data from microcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929178/c-need-to-receive-data-from-microcontroller](need) to receive data from microcontroller)

to know how to achieve the data from the microcontroller.